# how to sort a dictionary in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Here is my problem. I got this

```
{'Ciaran Johnson': {'PB': 58.2,
                    'Gender': 'M',
                    'Age': 6,
                    'Event': 'IM',
                    'Name': 'Ciaran Johnson'},
 'Joan Pine': {'PB': 44.0,
               'Gender': 'F',
               'Age': 6,
               'Event': 'FS',
               'Name': 'Joan Pine'},
 'Eric Idle': {'PB': 57.2,
               'Gender': 'M',
               'Age': 6,
               'Event': 'IM',
               'Name': 'Eric Idle'},
 'Kirsty Laing': {'PB': 58.2,
                  'Gender': 'F',
                  'Age': 6,
                  'Event': 'IM',
                  'Name': 'Kirsty Laing'}}
```

and I have to sort it firsty by gender,then event and lastle time(PB -the fastest to be first)

Comment: ... and what have you tried? Do you know that dictionnaries cannot be sorted in python?

Answer (score 3):

> I have this [`dict`] and I have to sort it...

You cannot sort a `dict`, since standard dictionaries are unordered. You can, however, use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
In [2]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [3]: sd = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k,v): (v['Gender'], v['Event'], v['PB'])))

In [4]: sd
Out[4]: OrderedDict([('Joan Pine', {'PB': 44.0, 'Gender': 'F', 'Age': 6, 'Event': 'FS', 'Name': 'Joan Pine'}), ('Kirsty Laing', {'PB': 58.2, 'Gender': 'F', 'Age': 6, 'Event': 'IM', 'Name': 'Kirsty Laing'}), ('Eric Idle', {'PB': 57.2, 'Gender': 'M', 'Age': 6, 'Event': 'IM', 'Name': 'Eric Idle'}), ('Ciaran Johnson', {'PB': 58.2, 'Gender': 'M', 'Age': 6, 'Event': 'IM', 'Name': 'Ciaran Johnson'})])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't sort a dictionary in Python, they are inherently unordered.

You can [sort the keys()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) though, which creates a list, and then use that list to access the elements in a fake ordered way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>> for k,v in sorted(spam.items(),key=lambda k:(k[1]['Gender'],k[1]['Age'],k[1]['PB'])):
    print(k,v)


Joan Pine {'PB': 44.0, 'Gender': 'F', 'Age': 6, 'Event': 'FS', 'Name': 'Joan Pine'}
Kirsty Laing {'PB': 58.2, 'Gender': 'F', 'Age': 6, 'Event': 'IM', 'Name': 'Kirsty Laing'}
Eric Idle {'PB': 57.2, 'Gender': 'M', 'Age': 6, 'Event': 'IM', 'Name': 'Eric Idle'}
Ciaran Johnson {'PB': 58.2, 'Gender': 'M', 'Age': 6, 'Event': 'IM', 'Name': 'Ciaran Johnson'}
>>>
```